# How to display Test Cases details in Jenkins Console Output?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng

I want to display Excel(XLSX) Test cases id,description and status while running selenium testng execution in the Jenkins Console output,below is the format.

```
TC_ID|Test Cases Description|Status
TC01|Verify Login Home|PASS
TC02|Verify Login Screen|FAIL
```

In case any one did this type of model please help me to achieve this in Jenkins Output Console.

Comment: Just to get you right, you mean that the content would be displayed post test class execution ? @Rajesh Om

Comment: @AutomatedOwl Yes post test class execution,Can you please provide code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TestNG in your project, anything you log using [Reporter](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters) class will be also printed in Jenkins console output :

```
Reporter.log("This will be displayed in the TestNG report AND in Jenkins console");
```

Note : You need to add the following import :

```
import org.testng.Reporter;
```

Refer [this](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/execute-testng-tests-using-jenkins/) link for steps to create a TestNG project in Jenkins. Alternatively, you can also as well create a Maven project where your pom file will execute your TestNG tests.

Now, if you want to get the data from an excel file, you can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). Refer [this](https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/) link for an example to read data from excel.

If you want PASS, FAIL status to be printed beside your test case name, you can use [`ITestResult`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.21/org/testng/ITestResult.html). Suppose you are printing the data in your `@AfterMethod` method, you would do something like -

```
@AfterMethod
public void afterSuite(ITestResult result)
{
  if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS)
    {
      //pass
    }
  else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
    {
            //fail
    }

  else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP )
    {    
             //skip
    }
}
```

Now, you can store the each respective test method result along with the name you read from the excel file, store it in a Map and then print it one by one in your `@AfterSuite` method.

Comment: How can i print in TCId|Test Description|Test Cases Status format in jenkins output using Reporter.log();

Comment: @RajeshOm Check my edited answer. Its one of the strategy you can use. If you face any difficulty in implementing it, ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will be better to implement listener but you can use code below:

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void beforeMethod(Method test, ITestResult testResult) {

    //get name of test. if testName annotation is empty get method name.
    String name = firstNonEmpty(
            test.getDeclaredAnnotation(org.testng.annotations.Test.class).testName(),
            test.getName()).get();

    String description = test.getDeclaredAnnotation(org.testng.annotations.Test.class).description();

    //get test result
    String result = "UNKNOWN";
    switch (testResult.getStatus()) {
        case 1:
            result = "SUCCESS";
            break;
        case 2:
            result = "FAILURE";
            break;
        case 3:
            result = "SKIP";
            break;
        case 4:
            result = "SUCCESS_PERCENTAGE_FAILURE";
            break;
        case 16:
            result = "STARTED";
            break;
    }

    //report as you wish..
    System.out.println(String.format("%s|%s|%s", name, description, result));
}
```